# Not able to cancel list of scheduled tasks using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, scheduled-tasks, executorservice

I have a class implementing Runnable interface

```
 class AppThread implements Runnable {
        String s;
        public AppThread(String s) {
            this.s=s;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(s);
            
        }
    }
```

I am creating few tasks and submitting to a ScheduledThreadPool and after waiting for 10 seconds cancelling the scheduled tasks.

```
    ScheduledExecutorService s = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    List<ScheduledFuture<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static void main( String... args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.method("A");
        app.method("D");
        app.method("C");
        app.method("B");
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        app.cancelTasks();
    }
 public void method(String s) {
        list.add(this.s.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AppThread(s), 1,2, TimeUnit.SECONDS));      
    }
```

I am successfully able to cancel the tasks using list.forEach
Method2

```
    public void cancelTasks() {
        System.out.println("Stopping Executors");
        this.list.forEach(sf -> sf.cancel(false));
    }
```

But when I do so using Java streams, I get not exception but the tasks still continue to execute.
Method2

```
    public void cancelTasks() {
        System.out.println("Stopping Executors");
        this.list.stream().map(sf-> sf.cancel(false));
    }
```

I am still trying to get hold of streams, but I do not understand why the second method doesn't work.

Comment: `map` is Intermediate operation which lazily loaded that's why there is no effect until terminal operation used

Comment: OP - please hover over the `stream` tag and read what it says. Once you understand it, edit your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is an *intermediate* operation, which doesn't do anything at all unless the list is *materialized* by a *terminal* operation. This way, you can effectively chain quite a lot of *intermediate* stream operations. This pattern is maybe better known as *lazy-evaluation*.

If you want to execute an action on each stream element, and do so immediately, you need to use `foreach`.

Thus, your code should become

```
 this.list.stream().forEach(sf-> sf.cancel(false));
```